# Windows 7 Federated Search & SharePoint 3 osdx file?

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint, wss-3.0

Can a osdx file be built for Sharepoint Services 3 to allow it to be included in Windows 7 Federated Search?  I see stuff for MOSS 2007, but I can't seem to get it to work for Sharepoint 3.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think WSS doesn't have an RSS feed for search results - which means it isn't usable as a Win7 Federated Search source.

If your WSS environment is single-server, you could upgrade for free to [Search Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-server-express.aspx) and gain this functionality (and a lot of other cool stuff).

If you have a multi-server WSS farm, then I don't think it is possible without paying to upgrade to MOSS or Search Server 2008